# Artificial mouse click for Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseclick-event

I have a function that binds a Button-1 mouse click to my Tkinter root. Now I want to artificially create a specific mouse click event, i.e. one that clicks a specific tk.Label (I have all tk.Label objects in a grid) in a different function, such that this function calls the mouse click function. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just call the function?  Why fake a click?

Comment: well the function takes as input an event. I'm not that familiar with tkinter yet. Idk if there's also a 'direct' way to generate the event that the function needs without faking a click? I thought that was the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose this is the wrong time to reorganize your app.  In many cases, if you need to fire an action from both an event and from normal code, you can separate the action part, and call it from both places.  But that's pretty picky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `event_generate` to generate an event:

```
the_label.event_generate("<1>", x=10, y=10)
```

Comment: Isn't `"<Button-1>"` more intuitive?

Comment: Thanks. What is x and y for? Does that specify the location of the click? Do I still need this? It looks like the event is generated in such a way that the click appears on the_label already anyways?

Comment: @joinijo: yes, it specifies the location of the click. Do you need it? No, I don't think you need it.